# SOT 23-6 SMD marking code

Tags: identification, surface-mount, code, sop

Can anyone help me with a SOT 23-6 manufacturer's marking code? I have searched, but no joy.

It is from a laptop inverter board.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi it's a laptop Inverter board

Comment: Where have you searched (to avoid repeating your failed endeavours)? Please list the places.

Answer (score 0):

MOSFET TSOP-6 AO6602 (KO6602)

Datasheet [here](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/676290/KEXIN/AO6602/459/3/AO6602.html)